# where is httpd.conf file in httpd-2.4.16 package?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I have downloaded **httpd-2.4.16.tar.gz** package from http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/

and extracted on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS two times but i am unable to find **conf** directory so that i configure **httpd.conf** file present in this directory as mentioned in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html#customize

One directory i found in this package at **/docs/conf** but in this package i found **httpd.conf.in** instead of **httpd.conf**  is it correct directory for configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Use  find /etc -name httpd

This will produce a list of all files within that directory that contain httpd

Or use:

> find / -name httpd.conf

which will produce the full path of wherever httpd.conf is situated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **conf** file appear after installation of apache. I was finding it inside extracted directory of  **httpd-2.4.16.tar.gz**.